# How to restrict special characters and numbers in a searchView?

Tags: android, textview

How can I allow only alphabetics (no special characters) in a search view control?

I tried following but it didn't work, it allows everything:

```
searchView.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_NORMAL);
```

*(I don't want to use editbox where there is an option of setting the digits in a XML property itself.)*

Docs: [TextView.inputMethod](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:inputMethod)

How can I make this work?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
EditText searchView= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtState);
Pattern ps = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z ]+$");
                Matcher ms = ps.matcher(searchView.getText().toString());
                boolean bs = ms.matches();
                if (bs == false) {
                    if (ErrorMessage.contains("invalid"))
                        ErrorMessage = ErrorMessage + "search,";
                    else
                        ErrorMessage = ErrorMessage + "invalid search,";

                }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may instead try:

```
searchView.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PERSON_NAME);
```

Or, you may set a check on the text entered. This function is a Kotlin extension function to check if a string contains only alphabets.

```
/**
 *
 *  *  Method to validate text for only alphabets
 */
fun String.isOnlyAlphabets(): Boolean {
    return Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z ]+$").matcher(this).matches()
}
```